# How to get concise syntax error messages from grako/TatSu

Tags: error-handling, exception, grako, tatsu

If the input to a grako/tatsu generated parser has a syntax error, such as `3 + / 3` to the calc.py examples, one gets a long list of Python calling sequences in addition to the relevant

`3 + / 3
    ^`

I could use `try` - `except` constructions but then I lose the relevant part of the error message as well.

I would like to use grako/tatsu to parse grammar rules for a rule compiler and I appreciate the possibility of separating the syntax and semantics in a clean way. The users would be quite annoyed of the excessive error messages. Is there a way for clean error messages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be the same as in any Python program. If you let the exception escape `main()`, then a stack trace will be printed. Instead, you can write:

```
try:
   do_parse()
except Exception as e:
  print(str(e))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now I think that I can handle the syntax errors the user makes when writing the rules. The str(e) gives me enough information and I think I can choose the essential information from that string. I still have problems in reporting errors which are detected in my semantic rules.  I use the `parse-factored()` of style parsing as in `calc.py`.

Comment: @koskenni You can also spelunk the exception object, which has some interesting information stored in it's attributes. See `tatsu.exceptions` for the definitions.